# Fetching child, grandchild using a parent attribute in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have a hibernate query.

```
Parent -> Child -> GrandChild
```

I have a `Parent` class which has a `one to many` relation to `Child` class and a `GrandChild` class which has one to many. I need to fetch all the corresponding child and grand child entities in an optimised way.

```
  public class Parent  {
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  private List<Child> children = new ArrayList<>();
```

}

```
public class Child {
 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private Parent parent;

  @OneToMany(
      mappedBy = "child",
      cascade = {CascadeType.ALL},
      orphanRemoval = true)
  private List<GrandChild> grandChild = new ArrayList<>();
}

public class GrandChild {
  @ManyToOne
  private Child child;
   
}
```

I already tried using join and then left join fetch but it doesn't work on all three levels. If the Grandchild has no values it works, otherwise not.
I don't want to make fetch type eager as it will have performance impact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. The direct query given below worked. But we need to add `@JsonIgnore` to the getters and setters of the parent(upper level) references in the child classes so as to not go in a recursive loop.

```
var query =
        em.createQuery(
            "select parent from Parent parent left join fetch parent.children "
                + "as children   where  parent.name=:name",
            Parent.class);
```

Hope it helps.